# JPQL List,Set IN Clause?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I want to compare two lists whether they subset of each other. I want to do it with `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` 
but Ive got a following exception:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [ADMIN] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]`

My query looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.roles in :roles ")
fun findByRoles(pageable: Pageable, roles: Set<Role>): Page<User>
```

Heres my entity classes:
@Entity

```
class User(
        var name: String,
        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "enum('ADMIN','USER')")
        @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role::class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        var roles: List<Role>,
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq")
        var id: Long? = null
)

enum class Role { ADMIN, USER }
```

And I put `[USER, ADMIN]` into my set.

Any idea?

**Update:**

When I modify the entities, it works. I changed the Role entity to class from enum.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cegportal_user")
class User(
        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false) var kauId: String,
        var name: String,

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id")])
        var roles: Set<Role>,

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "cegportal_user_id_seq", sequenceName = "cegportal_user_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cegportal_user_id_seq")
        var id: Long? = null
)

@Entity
class Role(
        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        var name: String,
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "role_id_seq", sequenceName = "role_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "role_id_seq")
        var id: Long? = null
)
```

Comment: I think you miss the `@Param("roles")` annotation in your `findByRoles` function

Comment: No, the problem is not the missing `@Param` annotation.

Comment: In is used to check if **one** element is contained in a set of elements. Not if a collection is a sub-collection of another one.